# Newspaper Delivery on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

Is getting a paper delivered on Shabbos allowed?

If not, what may be done with it upon delivery?

Comment: corollary: is a newspaper printed on shabbos muktzeh because of "nolad"?

Comment: I'm sure this is discussed, but IIRC some argue that as of Friday night, the newspaper is already sitting in the machines, waiting to be made into newspapers, so it may not be "nolad."

Comment: (Re the question.) As always, while this site is good[^W](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%5EW) great for discussion, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) with any _practical_ questions.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10350.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/640/mail-delivery-on-shabbos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This source seems to disagree:
http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v38/mj_v38i41.html#COA

It Seems to be quite complex.

Comment: My late rabbi occassionally quoted from that day's newspaper in his Shabbos drasha.  I assume he must have picked it up and read it.

Answer (score 3):

According to Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen's Sefer (will add in location later) in the name of both Rabbi Moshe Feinstein Zatzal and the Debertziner Rav Zatzal you are not allowed to get newspapers delivered on Shabbos.

Comment: Where I live, newspaper subscription is by the week, not by the day (except you can get a Sunday-only subscription).  Would the rabbis you cited hold that in that case you can't get a subscription because they'll deliver on Shabbat too, or would they just hold that you can't *specifically* order a paper for Shabbat?

Comment: I do not know, however Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen is listed in the Lakewood area and you can call him and ask him.

Comment: did you get a chance to edit the source in?

Answer (score -2):

There shouldn't be anything wrong if a delivery company decides to deliver a paper to your house on shabbos.

If I told you the talmudical expression "go out and see what the people do" you would conclude that it is also permissible to take it inside and read it.

Comment: So according to your interpretation of Pok Hazi, since most Jews drive to shul or for that matter do not observe Shabbos at all, would that now be okay?

Comment: That's a cleat violation of shabbos. This is not.

Comment: There is a mitzvah to judge people and their actions favorably.  How is this any different?  Poskim throughout history have always tried to justify seemingly bizarre minhagim!

Comment: @Yahu - I agree with you and not Azi (apr 2 '10 at 1:20). It would be okay. (in theory ... but- in practice, CYLOR)