# Newspaper delivery on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, mail

Is getting a Paper delivered on Yom Tov allowed? If not what may be done with it upon Delivery? as always (CYLOR)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/639/newspaper-delivery

Answer (score 3):

If a non-Jew delivers something outside the city limit on yomtov, it's prohibited to use it that day. It can, however, be used the next day.

So what if I wake up on the first day of Passover, and my non-Jewish neighbor knocks on the door and says, "Howdy! I just got up at the crack of dawn, drove to my farm 100 miles away, and picked a ton of apples. Here, have some!" I can't use them on the first day of Passover.

But on the second day, they should be okay to use.

*HOWEVER*, as cited by Chayei Adam, some authorities were concerned that people would ask non-Jews to make special deliveries on the first day of yomtov, so they could have it to use for the second day yomtov. There are therefore some who say you shouldn't use those apples on day 2 either. (Chayei Adam himself allows it "in cases of need, such as having out-of-town guests.")

My sense, therefore, is even if there's a problem using the paper the day it's delivered, it should be okay on the next day. (Unless you say we follow the stricter authorities, and extend cases with concern of ordering special deliveries to a paper that it's his normal job to deliver every day.)

Comment: Does this apply specifically to deliveries outside the city limit? What about someone who subscribes to 7 day newspaper delivery? Is this an issue with a Gentile doing work specifically for you? He is delivering papers to multiple people and it's his job. You are one of his stop offs.